# How to remove double space from string in mariadb or mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

In my MariaDB database table there are lots of names that contain double space. I would like to remove extra space from the string.

Example:

```
Name
........
Example  One
Example  Two
Example  Three
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `REGEXP_REPLACE` function in MariaDb and MySQL > 8

```
trim(REGEXP_REPLACE(name, "[ ]+", " "))
```

Here's a fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=96904642040f51ec3b438682cb34c96b

Answer (score 1):

Replace double space with single space

```
REPLACE(str,'  ',' ');
```